# Sums of powers of 2 in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to prove or disprove the following:

Let $(n_i)$ be any sequence of positive natural numbers. Then there is an $N>3$ such that, for any $[a]\in\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, there exists an $m\neq0$ such that

$$[\sum_{k=1}^{m}{2^{n_k}}]=[a].$$

I've tried an assortment of sequences on Mathematica and it seems like this is probably true. Unless the sequence is really nice (1,2,3,...), a totally general proof is unclear to me. This isn't out of a textbook or anything, it would just be really cool if true.

Comment: Do you want some size restrictions on $N$ to make the result non-trivial? If we take $N=1$ (say) then it becomes obvious.

Comment: I think a pigeonhole kind of argument should work in this case. It might also work if you change from $\exists N$ to $\forall N$ with $(N,2)=1$.

Comment: @LukeCollins Pigeonhole?

Comment: In all cases except when the sequence exactly alternates between odd and even, $N=3$ will work. Remains to find an $N$ for that case.

Comment: The [pigeonhole principle](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pigeonhole_principle) counting argument.

Comment: @SammyBlack I know what pigeonhole is, I was asking how the argument would work here.

Comment: @Arkady Yep, looking for a proof that addresses all sequences. Cases are fine, of course.

Comment: Yea, I’m saying that without loss of generality you can assume that the parity of the elements in your sequence alternate.

Comment: @Arkady: I think the requirement that $m \neq 0$ means that $N = 3$ won't work for an example like $1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, \ldots$, even though that doesn't alternate between odd and even: unless I've done the calculations wrong, you won't have a solution with $N = 3$ for $a = 0$.

Comment: @RobArthan you’re absolutely right. For my argument to work, I need a base number to start with and two consecutive odds or evens. Your example captures exactly this edge case.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't true as stated. Consider the nice sequence you suggested, (1,2,3,$\cdots$), and suppose there were some $N$ so that your claim was true. Notice that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n2^i=2^{n+1}-2.$$

Let $k$ be the integer so that $[-2]=[\sum_{i=1}^k2^i]=[2^{k+1}-2].$ Then $[0]=[2^{k+1}],$ implying that $2^{k+1}$ is a multiple of $N$ which is impossible. (Note that $N$ can be assumed to be relatively prime to 2 from the start, or else it would be impossible for every element of $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ to be represented by a sum of powers of 2, i.e. a multiple of 2).

Regardless, it's interesting to think about which sequences this is true for. For instance, checking Mathematica, this weirdly enough is true for the sequence $(n^2)$ for $N=101$ (and lots of other $N$).

Another fun note: for every such sequence where this is true, you have ruled out a possible behavior of the prime gap sequence by elementary means. For if there is a $p$ so that the sequence of primes becomes $p,p+2^{n_1},p+2^{n_1}+2^{n_2},...$ then you can go appropriately far so that one of the partial sums is congruent to $-p$ mod $N$ (meaning that the corresponding "prime" is in fact divisible by $N$). Neat!